# How to make a cartesian product in jq?

Tags: json, shell, jq

Let say I have input

```
[  
   {  
      "a":1,
      "b":2
   },
   {  
      "a":3,
      "b":4
   }
]
```

and I tried,

```
echo '[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]' | jq '[{x: .[].a, y: .[].b}]'
```

and I would like to get

```
[  
   {  
      "x":1,
      "b":2,
      "language":"en"
   },
   {  
      "x":1,
      "b":2,
      "language":"fr"
   }...
]
```

Meaning I need to for all items in array I need output two items, one with added `"lanuage": "en"` key value pair and one with `"lanuage": "ru"`

EDIT. In case it's not clear enoug. I need a catesian product of input array of objects `is` with another array `xs`, which would give me pairs `(i, x)`. For each pair I want to output object that have all (key, value) pairs of `i` plus some key (`language` in my case) with with value of `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, any expression that generates multiple values combined with another expression that generates multiple values will create a cartesian product.

i.e.,

```
"\(1,2) \(3,4)"
```

generates strings `"1 3"`, `"2 3"`, `"1 4"`, and `"2 4"`.

You can do the same given an array of values.  `[]` will take the array and generate a result for each of the items.  So combining these concepts, you could do something like this:

```
$ jq --argjson langs '["en","fr"]' '[(.[]|{x:.a,b}) + {language:$langs[]}]' input.json
```

But this could further be reduced to simply:

```
$ jq --argjson langs '["en","fr"]' '[.[]|{x:.a,b,language:$langs[]}]' input.json
```

or

```
$ jq --argjson langs '["en","fr"]' 'map({x:.a,b,language:$langs[]})' input.json
```

Comment: This almosts works, but outputs invalid json and I need an array. How to do that?

Comment: Well, it's a stream of json objects. If you need the stream as an array, just add square brackets to put them into an array.

Comment: Well, I've tried this `echo '[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]' | jq --argjson langs '["en", "fr"]' '.[] | [{x: .a, y: .b, language: $langs[]}]'`. This makes stream of arrays.